# icon inside button does not trigger attached function on React

Tags: html, reactjs

I am building app on React. I have a table of item list and have difficult invoking function on icon.

[image]

```
deleteItem = event => {
    this.props.deleteRecord(event);
};

const RecordList = records.map(({ category, task, duration, id }, i) => (
        <tr className="record-item" key={i} id={id}>
            <td>
                <span className="recordItem">{category}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>{task}</span>
            </td>
            <td className="time-trashIcon-container">
                <span>{duration}</span>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    className="trashIcon"
                    id={id}
                    onClick={this.deleteItem}
                >
                    <i className="far fa-trash-alt" />
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    ));
```

**What I want to achieve**

when user clicks the trash button (icon inside button tag), it calls a function to delete item.

**Problem**

For now, *only when I click button padding, not icon itself* triggers delete function. Clicking icon does not trigger anything.

**What I tried** 
I wrap the icon inside span and tried giving delete function as onClick eventListener. It would trigger a function but it fails to find property I want to pass *id of each item* which I need to delete the target item.

I don't want to use jQuery. I have tried `data-x` to pass property and did not work either. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you tons in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for anyone who might have a similar problem :)

After trying a few things out below...

- `<a id={id} onClick={this.delete}`>
- `<button id={id} onClick={this.delete}><a id={id} onClick={this.delete}><i className='trashIcon'></a></button>`
- `<button id={id} onClick={this.delete}><span id={id} onClick={this.delete}><i className='trashIcon'></span></button>`

All of them invoke delete function when clicking padding of icon, not the icon itself.

The working code was just to put `<span><i/><span>`

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside button. using below syntax you need not to bind if you are using `ES6`

```
onClick={e => this.deleteItem(id, e)}
```

write your delete code inside.

```
deleteItem(id, event) {
       //TO-DO delete code
}
```

Instead of using button you can use `<a>`

```
<a  className="trashIcon"
    id={id}
    onClick={e => this.deleteItem(id, e)}/> <i className="far fa-trash-alt"/></a>
```

Comment: Neither of `<button><i/></button` and `<a>` tag work. I tried several things out and it was simple `<span><i/></span>`. Thanks for the comment though! Have a good day!